# Definition in Complex Geometry - Huybrechts

Tags: definition, differential-forms, complex-geometry

In the book Complex Geometry -  Huybrechts. The author says that the $k-$th wedge product of the holomorphic cotangent bundle $T^\ast X$ is the set of holomorphic $k-$forms. I know that an holomorphic $k-$ form is a **section** of the wedge product-bundle(WPB). Why the author calls a point of WPB "holomorphic form"?

Comment: That's not what the book says (at least not my edition). Definition 2.2.14 says "*The bundle of holomorphic $p$-forms is $\Omega_X^p:= \bigwedge^p\Omega_X$ [...]*"

Comment: Yes, but $\Omega_X$ is just the dual bundle of $TX$.

Comment: The point of my comment is that Huybrechts didn't write "the set of holomorphic k-forms".

Comment: Yes, but I think that "bundle" or "set" is the same in this contest.

Comment: I think that that is not correct. By "bundle of X" he means "bundle whose sections are X": Huybrechts often uses bundles and their spaces of sections interchangeably.